# Problem evaluating results of DSolve (Power::infy)

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

So, after browsing through older posts to see if anybody else could have had the same problem, I have come to the conclusion that I am stuck. That bothers me, especially because it should be straight forward.

I am trying to solve a Differential Equation. The equation is:
[image: Image of the Differential Equation to be solved, including the time domain]

I would like to find X(t), and hence plot X as a function of time. It is known that X = 0 when t = 0.

I write this the following way:

```
solOpg13a1 = 
   DSolve[{D[X[t], t] == (k*(1 - X[t])*(t*Fa - X[t]*nB0))/(V0 + t*v0), X[0] == 0}, X[t], t];
```

Next, I prepare it for plotting by the following:

```
eqOpg13a1 = X[t] /. solOpg13a1 //. {k -> 5.1 , V0 -> 1500 , nB0 -> 1125 , Fa -> 6.0, v0 -> 4} // First;
```

Please note that V0 and v0 are not the same.

X(t) works OK for values above 150 (more or less). For values of t less than around 150, I get a series of Power::infy and Infinity::indet errors.

[image: Screendumpt of errors and plot]

It should be straight forward, and so I am sorry to call for help, but I just can't put a finger on where I go wrong.

The time to t_full is approximately 250 Hours (which is the unit of t). I am using Mathematica 9.

Comment: I think it's just an issue of balancing big numbers. This will work : `aux[t_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  X[t] /. First@
    DSolve[{D[X[t], 
        t] == (k*(1 - X[t])*(t*Fa - X[t]*nB0))/(V0 + t*v0), 
      X[0] == x0}, X[t], t]]`, `sol[t_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   aux[t] /. {x0 -> 0., k -> 5.1/100, V0 -> 1500, nB0 -> 1125, 
     Fa -> 6, v0 -> 4}]` and then plot/use `sol[t]`.

Comment: I also found out the problem can be solved by usingNDSolve instead, for the range {t,0,250}. This gave the plot that I was expecting.

Comment: The laziest of all approaches :D `Plot[X[t] /. FullSimplify@sol /. {x0 -> 0., k -> 5.1/100, V0 -> 1500, 
   nB0 -> 1125, Fa -> 6, v0 -> 4}, {t, 0, 300}]` produces [this plot of the solution](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vBVUk.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is fairly straight forward:

```
Plot[X[t] /. FullSimplify@sol /. 
    {x0 -> 0., k -> 5.1/100, V0 -> 1500, nB0 -> 1125, Fa -> 6, v0 -> 4}, {t, 0, 300}]
```

Producing

> [image: Plot]